# Uniform Sampling From the Region Bounded by $\sqrt{x}$, $x=3$, and $y=0$

Tags: sampling, density-function, uniform-distribution

I want to sample uniformly from the area bounded by $y=0$, $x=3$, and $y=\sqrt{x}$:
[image]

If I draw $x$ from $U[0, 3]$ and $y$ from $U[0, \sqrt{x}]$, the density will be higher in the bottom left corner:
[image]

I tried to fix this by making the number of points on a region bounded by $x=a \in [0, 3]$ on the right, the square root curve, and the $x$-axis proportional to its area (relative to that of the entire figure).

So, the total area should be: $$\int_{0}^{3}\sqrt{x}dx = \frac{2}{3}x^{\frac{3}{2}}\bigg\rvert_{0}^{3}=2\sqrt{3}$$

The area bounded by $x=a$ on the right is $\frac{2}{3}a^{\frac{3}{2}}$, so the pdf of $x$ should be proportional to the ratio, i.e.:
$$
pdf(x) = C \times \frac{\frac{2}{3}a^{\frac{3}{2}}}{2\sqrt{3}} = \frac{C}{3\sqrt{3}}a^{\frac{3}{2}}
$$

The corresponding CDF is then:

$$
CDF(x) = \int_{0}^{x} pdf(u)du = \int_{0}^{x} \frac{C}{3\sqrt{3}}u^{\frac{3}{2}}du = \frac{C}{3\sqrt{3}} \times \frac{2}{5} u^{\frac{5}{2}} \bigg\rvert_{0}^{x}
$$

$$
CDF(x) = \frac{C}{3\sqrt{3}} \times \frac{2}{5} x^{\frac{5}{2}} = \frac{2C}{5\times3\sqrt{3}} x^{\frac{5}{2}}
$$

I get $C$ from the condition $CDF(3)=1$:
$$
CDF(3) = \frac{2C}{5\times3\sqrt{3}} 3^{\frac{5}{2}} = \frac{2C}{5}\times 3 = \frac{6C}{5} = 1
$$
So:
$$
C = \frac{5}{6} \implies \quad CDF(x) = \left(\frac{x}{3}\right)^{\frac{5}{2}}
$$

Therefore, I should sample $x$ by sampling a random number $r \in Uniform[0, 1]$ and solving $CDF(x)=r$ for $x$:
$$
x = 3 \times r^{\frac{2}{5}} \quad (r \in Uniform[0,1])
$$

and get $y$ by sampling from $Uniform[0, \sqrt{x}]$. However, this approach doesn't make the distribution uniform:
[image]
The sampled points are now concentrated away from the bottom left corner.

Can someone help me? :)

Comment: in terms of simplicity of implementation, it's going to be hard to beat rejection sampling: sample many $u\sim U([0,3]\times[0,\sqrt{3}]$. Keep only those for which $u_y\leq\sqrt{u_x}$. That's your sample.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The distribution of $y$ conditional on $x$ is uniformly distributed between $0$ and $\sqrt x.$

Within any narrow vertical strip of width $\mathrm dx$ around $x$ you want the frequency of points to be proportional to $\sqrt{x}\,\mathrm d x$.  Adding these up (integrating) tells us **the cumulative distribution of the $x$ coordinates must be proportional to $x^{3/2}.$** Since the full proportion of $1$ is attained at $x=3,$ the distribution function must be

$$F_X(x) = \left(\frac{x}{3}\right)^{3/2}.$$

**The most direct way to sample from this distribution** is by generating uniform quantiles.  That is, when $U$ has a uniform distribution on $[0,1],$

$$F_x^{-1}(U) = 3U^{2/3}$$

has the distribution $F_X.$

Thus, by generating $2n$ uniform random variates you can obtain $n$ points uniformly drawn from this region.

Here is an implementation in `R`.

```R
n <- 1e3; y <- sqrt(x <- 3 * runif(n) ^ (2/3)) * runif(n)
```

A scatterplot might look like this:

[image]

**One way to check the validity** is to slice a set of points *horizontally* in a thin band and check for a uniform distribution, *except* near the smallest values (where there will an edge effect).  After generating a million points, for instance, I plotted a thin band around $y=1.5$ with the commands

```R
dy <- 0.01
y0 <- 1.5
hist(x[abs(y - y0) <= dy/2])
```

There were 2140 points with this nearly uniform histogram:

[image]

Similar histograms emerge at other values of `y0`.